# Using Client Credetials as the part of Usermanager<User>

Tags: openiddict

Currently i am using `Password Flow` with my SPA application.

Now i had to integrate `Client Credentials` flow with my current implementation.

```
var descriptor = new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
{
    ClientId = "console",
    ClientSecret = "388D45FA-B36B-4988-BA59-B187D329C207",
    DisplayName = "My client application",
    Permissions =
{
    OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
    OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.ClientCredentials
}
```

I have successfully implemented the both integration on my system. When sending the request using the `client_id` the app is authorized and authenticated as expected.

But as i notice that when using the `Password flow` i as using `ApplicationUser` as a part of Asp.net identity from dbo.User table.

But `client credentials` comes from different namespace that is not linked up with the Application User.

How can i setup the `client_id` as the part of `dbo.User`. How to link the the `Client Credetials` with `Usermanager<User>`?

Why i want this implementation is because during the crud operation i have the column name `CreatedBy`. which is refrenced to table `dbo.User` and i wanted to fill up the `Id` from dbo.User. But in the client credetials flow do not have the `User`.

**Getting UserId**

```
 public interface IUserResolverService
 {
    HttpContext HttpContext { get; }
    Task<Guid> GetUserId();           
 }

  public class UserResolverService : IUserResolverService
  {
        IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnv;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;
        private readonly UserManager<User> _user;
        public UserResolverService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor, UserManager<User> user, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv)
        {
            this._user = user;
            this.accessor = accessor;
            this._hostingEnv = hostingEnv;
        }
        public HttpContext HttpContext
        {
            get { return accessor.HttpContext; }
        }

        public async Task<Guid> GetUserId()
        {
            var user = await _user.GetUserAsync(accessor.HttpContext.User);
            return user?.Id ?? Guid.Empty;
        }
   }
```

Can you suggest me a way for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i setup the client_id as the part of dbo.User. How to link the the Client Credetials with Usermanager?

It's not possible and it doesn't make any sense, actually. The client credentials is the only OAuth 2.0 core flow that doesn't involve any user as it's been designed for service-to-service scenarios, where the client application doesn't act on behalf of a user, but directly under its own identity.

To work around your issue, you may want to either make `CreatedBy` nullable or use one of the claim representing the application you use in `AuthorizationController`, like the client identifier or the client name.

Comment: I set the `client_id` as the username from the `User` table and Add that on the claim. I retrieve the user details using the below code.
`var email = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject)?.Value;`
`var user = await _user.FindByEmailAsync(email);`
I have implemented in this way to get the `CreatedBy` Id